# Android EditText in ScrollView pans to the top when more text is inserted

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an `EditText` inside a `LinearLayout` which resides inside a `ScrollView`. Underneath the `EditText` are a bunch of `TextViews` to fill up the screen (and beyond). The `EditText` has a `layout_height` of 100dp so that it has room for a few lines of text.

Now when i start typing in the `EditText` and hit "enter" to add a new line after a couple of lines the entire layout (including the `ScrollView`) start to pan to the top until the entire `EditText` is not visible anymore.

[image: Content should not pan upwards]

Apparently the "panning" towards the top starts when the "virtual" height of text inside the `EditText` (the View bounds remain 100dp high) reaches a certain threshold.

On the activity i have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but a similar problem occurs with `adjustResize`.

I have also tried to play around with the `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on the ScrollView or the various min and max properties on the `EditText` but nothing did help

Here is the layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Hallo World!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:text="I am an EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top|start" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Hallo World!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Hallo World!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        ... many more text views ...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Does anybody know how i could prevent the entire layout from panning upward when entering text with new lines into the `EditText`?

Comment: Did you figure out a fix yet? I'm having this issue right now.

Comment: @slai47 Sadly not. But i haven't looked into it much more since i couldn't figure it out.